# How to correct indentation in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation

How can indentation be automatically (not manually) corrected in IntelliJ?

In Eclipse, it's possible to just highlight the code that needs indenting, right-click, and select `Source` > `Correct indentation`.

Is there any method for doing the same thing in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

`Code` → `Reformat Code...` (default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) for the whole file or `Code` → `Auto-Indent Lines` (default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) for the current line or selection.

You can customise the settings for how code is auto-formatted under `File` → `Settings` → `Editor` → `Code Style`.

---

To ensure comments are also indented to the same level as the code, you can simply do as follows:

[image: UI screenshot]
<sub>(example for JavaScript)</sub>

Comment: it doesn't work for comments, is there any way for auto-indent for comments. I want to format code and comments of the same way that eclipse does.

Comment: is there a way to do it for all classes in my project?

Comment: @ZiadHalabi reformat code from the project root context menu.

Comment: It is working, but only for lines beginning with `*`(line comments). If you have a paragraph block comments, with only first line beginning with `/*` and after last line ending with `*/`, with all intermediate line beginning with text, it does not work, when it also should. So... the logic is a little bit.. naive?

Answer (score 191):

Just select the code and

- on Windows do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
- on Linux do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
- on Mac do <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: consider accepting existing answer instead of answering yourself with exactly the same (Reformat Code... is Ctrl+Alt+L in the default Windows keymap).

Comment: In Linux you will lock the screen. WTH this shortcurt is in the linux version? hahah

Comment: It is the same... Ctrl-Alt-L (I'm using Android Studio)... which is a small shame among other shames. Hopefully, the adoption of Android Studio will provide more traction to the Linux version.

Comment: In Linux, you can use it with the 'Super' (or Windows) key. So, Ctrl + Alt + Super + L, does the required indentation.

Comment: For mac, use CMD+Alt+L

Comment: is there a way to do it for all classes in my project?

Comment: There is no ALt key in mac. What are you guys talking about?

Comment: actually i have the problem with reformat function of IntelliJ, indent should be tabs, adding spaces for var params on constructor for Typescript

Comment: Its' ALT + SHIFT + L on Linux now. Good. (Because CTRL + WIN + ALT + L is for the Ayyyy Lmaos, really)

Comment: @ZhenLiu Of course there is. It's **⌥** (ALT Option) key. Here how it's look like on:
[Mac keyboard](https://www.macworld.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3462401/Mac_keyboard_800home.jpg)

Answer (score 9):

Select Java editor settings for Intellij
[image: Settings]
Select values for Tabsize, Indent & Continuation Intent 
 (I choose 4,4 & 4)

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to format your file (or your selection).

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> works with Android Studio under xfce4 on Linux.  I see that Gnome used to use this shortcut for lock screen, but in Gnome 3 it was changed to Super+L (AKA Windows+L):
https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio this works:
Go to File->Settings->Editor->CodeStyle->Java. 
Under Wrapping and Braces uncheck "Comment at first Column"
Then formatting shortcut will indent the comment lines as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try out <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> even though you can also use <kbd>L</kbd> as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution of *unchecking `comment at first column`* is partially working, because it works for line comments, but not block comments.

So, with lines like:

```
/* first line
 * second line
 * ...
 */
```

or

```
// line 1
// line 2
// line 3
...
```

they are indented with "Auto reformat", but lines like:

```
/* first line
   second line
   ...
 */
```

the identation will not be fixed.

So you should:

- add `*` or `//` before each line of comments
- then uncheck `Keep when reformatting -> comment at first column`
- and `Auto reformat`.

Comment: `Line selection mode` will help you(mouse middle key). To add line comments, search for `line comment` in key maps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to fix the indentation for the code you've selected, you can press:
`Ctrl + Alt + I`

FYI: I'm on Windows and using IntelliJ IDE.