# IntelliJ keeps making some of my code in-line

Tags: intellij-idea

Whenever I start up IntelliJ it always does this to my setter methods, It makes them in-line and it's really annoying. Does anyone know how to change this?

[image]

Comment: Edit your preferences and tell IntelliJ to stop making these formatting changes, q.v. [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044472/correct-indentation-in-intellij).

Comment: I don't know what the preference is to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings > Editor > General > Code Folding` and in `Collapse By default` section, disable `One-line methods` checkbox:

[image]

Comment: While this is a correct way to achieve what is asked for, the question is no entirely correct. In this Idea does not format the code, but just collapses the section.