# Lambda expression indentation

Tags: rider

What setting in Rider is responsible for what lambdas find on such a large indent?

For example i want this:

[image]

instead this:

[image]

Comment: checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9044517/10305444) link

Comment: Not the save, I have a question here how to change the length of the indentation for lambdas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> `C#` -> `Tabs, Indent, Alignment` -> `Align Multiple Constructs`.

Specifically for lambdas: `Array, object and collection initialization`, `Anonymous method body` must be turned off